# Data structures for graphs

Tags: data-structures, hashtable, graph-theory

I am currently writing my master's thesis. It's about graphs. My algorithm is ready. But now I have to think about useful data structures to represent the graph and the rest that I need for a good runtime. I am not allowed to use the adjacency matrix because of the large amount of memory. Since I have to check in every iteration whether a certain edge exists, adjacency lists also make no sense.

First I thought about two hash tables nested inside one another. All nodes are stored in the first table and all neighboring nodes in the second.
But since I have to be able to choose a random neighbor in my algorithm, that is not optimal either.
In addition, I have to be able to save edge weights in every iteration of the algorithm.

A list with all the basic operations:

- I need a presentation of the edges where I can check in O (1) if there is a certain edge exists
- I must be able to choose a random neighbor of a fixed node in O(1)
- I need to be able to assign weights to the edges in O (1)
- I also need to find out what the degree of a knot is in O (1)

I am allowed to use different data structures for all operations. Unfortunately, I'm running out of ideas.

I hope someone here can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Lisa

Comment: Make a list of all of the basic/atomic operations you need to perform and how fast they need to be.  Then we can help by suggesting data structures that meet those requirements.

Comment: How many vertices and edges is the graph expected to have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

A map data structure where the keys are implemented as a hashtable to give you O(1) access/insert/delete time. The keys of this map will be your nodes.

The values of this map data structure will be sets, also implemented as hashtables, to give you O(1) access/insert/delete time. The members of these sets are neighboring nodes to the key.

For the weights of the edges you have a few options. You can insert tuples into the sets of the the adjacency list where say the first value is the neighboring node and the second value is the weight of the edge connecting those two nodes. The weight can be updated in O(1) time since both the map and the sets are implemented as hashtables.

You can store the degrees of the nodes in a separate map data structure where the keys (implemented as hashtable) are the nodes and the values are the degrees. This will provide O(1) access/delete/update time to each node's degree.

To achieve O(1) time for random edges connected to a node you need to use an additional data structure. The reason is that the edges stored in the sets (as hashtables), won't give us a way to get a random number in O(1). But if we store each node's edges in a list/array like data structure, we can get a random index between 0 and the length of that array in O(1) and access that edge in O(1).

This method, will cover your time complexity requirements by adding to the space needed, although the space complexity does not increase.

Instead of separate data structures you could create classes that combine them in one place.

I can add simplified implementations if necessary.

Comment: "The keys of this map will be your nodes."  This seems odd.  I would expect the mapped values to be the nodes.

Comment: Both the keys of the map and the members of the set in the value are nodes. The keys are the source nodes and the values in the sets are the destination nodes. It's an adjacency list.

Comment: What happens when a node has multiple out edges?

Comment: The value of the map data structure is a `set` itself implemented as a hashtable. This value can hold unique members, provided the members are hashable themselves. I am assuming that the members are integers representing the destination nodes, just like the keys of the map. Even if the nodes are not integers, say they are more complex classes holding different types of data, a hashing function can be devised for them. This is implementation specific. A `set` implemented as a hashtable, gives O(1) access/delete/add time.

Comment: It all sounds horribly complicated, hard to understand and impossible to maintain.  I wonder what the performance of all this is going to be.  The straightforward design I propose can do a complete DFS traversal of a graph with 0.4M nodes and 3.4M edges in 0.5 secs.  Details https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder2/wiki/Performance

Comment: I am not invalidating your solution.  What I'm proposing are general design guidelines that probably need to be considered in any implementation that covers OP's TC requirements.  I wrote this answer because I didn't see your solution cover all the requirements of OP (Specifically, the O(1) random access and node degree requirements). As to complexity, I don't think it is very complicated relative to the requirements and would be happy to see a simpler solution that covers all requirements. Anyway, that's why data structures need to be fully tested and the details abstracted away.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the detailed answer!
I’ve read it several times, and I’ve understood what you mean. My problem is that my professor wants a very detailed description when I say I save the nodes with the sets in a hash table. I’m supposed to describe in detail how this works with perfect hashing. Which, unfortunately, I have problems with. That’s why I’ve been thinking about your ideas again myself. I wanted to ask you if you think it’s possible this way.

Comment: When I save my graph as an adjacency list, I need less storage space than an adjacency matrix. The degree of the nodes corresponds to the length of the respective lists, so O(1). And in the respective lists I can choose random neighbors in O(1). For the rest, I had the idea that I could assign an ID to each edge, as well as to the nodes. Then I could create the object Edge and assign the attributes node 1, node 2 and edge weight to this object. And then I can hash these edges normally. So I can check in O(1) whether an edge exists and I can access the edge weights in O(1).
What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using maps, which provide fast lookup of vertices and edges in a sparse graph ( one with few edges relative to the number of vertices )

Each vertex stores a map of its out edges, keyed by the destination vertex index.  The graph is stored in a map of vertices, keyed by vertex index.

For a detailed description of this design: https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder2/wiki/cGraph-Class-Design

The repository also stores C++ code implementing the design and many implementations of graph theory algorithms using the the design.

Answer (score 0):

> I need a presentation of the edges where I can check in O (1) if there is a certain edge exists
>
> I need to be able to assign weights to the edges in O (1)

That's a hash map from edge to weight.  The key is just the pair of vertex numbers.  If this is an *undirected* graph, then order the numbers in the pair so that the smaller one is first.

> I must be able to choose a random neighbor of a fixed node in O(1)
>
> I also need to find out what the degree of a knot is in O (1)

That's a map from each vertex to an array of its neighboring vertices -- i.e., an adjacency list representation of the graph, ensuring the each adjacency list is in a structure that supports random access.

Answer (score 0):

For a complete and comprehensive data structures for Graph you can check the [CXXGraph](https://github.com/ZigRazor/CXXGraph) library.
Is an open source Header-Only library easily readable.